# Adding Sparkline to a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add sparkline for the average of last 4 weeks of the data mentioned in last four columns of the entire data.

Below is a piece of code(only sparkline related) i have, but it is throwing error

```
Set rng = Cells(6, Range("E5").End(xlToRight).Column + 3)
Set sparkrange = Range(Cells(6, Range("E5").End(xlToRight).Column - 3), Cells(6, Range("E5").End(xlToRight).Column))
rng.SparklineGroups.Add Type:=xlSparkLine, SourceData:=sparkrange
```

The error is Run-Time Error'13':Type mismatch
It is showing error for this line of the code :

```
rng.SparklineGroups.Add Type:=xlSparkLine, SourceData:=sparkrange
```

Please Help !!

Answer (score 0):

Got this working with the below code, by referencing the 'address' of the sparkrange variable. I believe the Source Data argument must be a String data type which the ".Address" should give.

```
Set rng = Cells(6, Range("E5").End(xlToRight).Column + 3)
Set sparkrange = Range(Cells(6, Range("E5").End(xlToRight).Column - 3), Cells(6, Range("E5").End(xlToRight).Column))
rng.SparklineGroups.Add Type:=xlSparkLine, SourceData:=CStr(sparkrange.Address)
```